# Verificar elementos e fazer a troca entre Arrays Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Preciso fazer uma função na minha classe Team que irá verificar meu array para ver se o player existe, se não existir, retornará um erro, se existir, fará uma troca entre os dois arrays.

Exemplo: Tenho uma matriz com jogadores titulares e reservas, os jogadores 1,2 e 3 são titulares e os jogadores 4,5 e 6 são reservas.

então quando eu quiser fazer uma troca de jogadores, posso usar algo como: Team.swapfunc(player1, player4) ou algo semelhante

Meu código de exemplo:

```
class SoccerPlayers {
let name: String
let number: Int
init(name: String, number: Int) {

    self.name = name
    self.number = number
}
}
class Team {

    var nameTeam: String

    // Array of players
    var startingPlayers:[SoccerPlayers] = []
    var reservePlayers:[SoccerPlayers] = []

    init(nameTeam:String, startingPlayers: [SoccerPlayers], reservePlayers: [SoccerPlayers]) {
        self.nameTeam = nameTeam
        self.startingPlayers = startingPlayers
        self.reservePlayers = reservePlayers
    }
}

var player1: SoccerPlayers = SoccerPlayers(    
    name: "Andre",
    number: 1
)

var player2: SoccerPlayers = SoccerPlayers(    
    name: "Joao",
    number: 2
)

var player3: SoccerPlayers = SoccerPlayers(    
    name: "Matheus",
    number: 3
)

var player4: SoccerPlayers = SoccerPlayers(    
    name: "Junior",
    number: 4
)

var player5: SoccerPlayers = SoccerPlayers(    
    name: "Fabio",
    number: 5
)

var player6: SoccerPlayers = SoccerPlayers(
    name: "Paulo",
    number: 6
)

let team1 = Team(nameTeam:"YourTeam", startingPlayers:[player1, player2, player3], reservePlayers:[player4, player5, player6])
 }
```

obs: este código é apenas para estudo, não é um projeto de trabalho real

Answer (score 0):

Pode criar um terceiro array para armazenar um dos dois valores

```
func swapPlayers() {
    let temporary = startingPlayers
    startingPlayers = reservePlayers
    reservePlayers = temporary
}
```